# What are -applicationDidFinishLaunching and -applicationWillFinishLaunch?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, cocoa-touch

Can somebody explain for me the difference between iOS  **applicationDidFinishLaunching** and OSX **applicationWillFinishLaunch** methods?

If it is possible, you can give me a reference and I can go over it.

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3):

**applicationWillFinishLaunching** isn't available for iPhone apps is only for Mac OS X applications.
It's a notification that is sent by the default notification center immediately before the application object is initialized.

**applicationDidFinishLaunching** This method tells the delegate when the application has launched. But apple recommends to use the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: instead.

**UPDATE**: As mentioned on the comment below applicationWillFinishLaunching is available for iOS starting iOS 6.

Comment: applicationWillFinishLaunching is available for iOS,
    `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(nullable NSDictionary *)launchOptions NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);`

This is what UIApplication.h shows

Comment: applicationWillFinishLaunching was not available when I answered that question, now it is so I updated my comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of applicationWillFinish launch, but the other one is the event that is fired when the application has launched and you can begin to execute you're apps logic.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

The 'Will' comes before the 'Did'
Like in view controllers, the ViewWillAppear fires before the ViewDidAppear